# How to use Visual Studio automatic brace completion to surround an existing block?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, ide

The problem I have with Visual Studio automatic brace completion is that it neglects to understand that I'm trying to surround an entire block. For this reason I habitually disable it, but they've defaulted this to 'on' for years, so I thought I'd try to find out if I'm missing something about how to use Visual Studio efficiently... wouldn't be the first time I went for years without knowing some basic editing feature.

The main problematic case is when I try to surround text, starting with something like `lock (myMutex) {` around a list of commands:

```
// Imagine I just typed the following line, where ^ is the cursor
lock (myMutex) {^ }  // <---  it just auto-added " }" to the end.
command1();
command2();
command3();
// where I plan to put the "}"
```

I then have to press delete the correct number of times to undo the auto-formatting and the wrongly placed braces command, in order to proceed with scooting the cursor down to complete the surrounding.

This seems to be by far the common case, making the braces autocompletion very annoying. Am I doing something wrong? Is there some keyboard sequence I can enter that would sanely result in what I want that I should be using, that I just don't know about? Or am I correct to just disable this every time I reinstall VS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know there is nothing built-in in Visual Studio for this task. There are some tools (not free) that greatly improve the Visual Studio editing experience. But as I have said they are not free and sometimes they tend to slow down also the basic operation of Visual Studio.

However you could create a `SurroundsWith` snippet. A little automation wizard that you could retrieve and execute also in Visual Studio 2015 right clicking on the selected block of code that you want to be surrounded by braces.

- First thing is to download the `Snippet Designer` using the
  Extensions and Updates from the TOOLS menu.
- Then open the menu FILE -> NEW -> FILE and choose Snippet Designer
  then Code Snippet.
- In the Snippet editor add these lines

  ```
  {
      $selected$ $end$ 
  }
  ```
- Then give a name entering some text in the Snippet box and select C#
  as language.
- Save the Snippet taking note where has been saved.
- Now open the Snippet with any text editor of your choice and change
  the value `<SnippetType>` with

  ```
  <SnippetType>SurroundsWith</SnippetType>
  ```
- Save the file.

Usually, at this point, Visual Studio should be able to recognize immediately the new snippet but in any case you could close and reopen the IDE.

Now if you select a block of code, right click and choose `Surrounds With` (<kbd>Ctrl+K</kbd><kbd>S</kbd>), `MyCodeSnippets` and then your named snippet you will have your code indented

If you are interested you could find a lot more details about the Snippets functionality at this page on MSDN: [`Creating Code Snippets`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms165393(v=VS.100).aspx)

Comment: Thanks, using this method, I'd likely be doing shift+downdowndown to select, and then I need to punch in the hotkey for the snippet. However, I just discovered that return,alt+downdowndown will actually scoot the closing bracket down through the code in pretty minimal keystrokes for small blocks, but I need to manually trigger the format afterwards so it evens out.

Comment: Oh, gosh, I did not know, well yes the keystrokes required are more or less the same. However I hope the answer will be useful also for other tasks. I use snippets a lot.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem with the help of [AutoHotKey](https://autohotkey.com/). I already use this program as a text expander, I simply added:

```
send, {{}{enter}{}}
```

to "expand" an open curly bracket with its closed counterpart on a new line. I then go down to that closed bracket and move the whole row with <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>DOWN</kbd> after the block I want to surround.