# How to automatically move opening bracket on a new line and add closing curly bracket in Visual Studio 2015?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

Meet long time reader, first time poster :P

At the moment I have to manually type opening curly bracket, then closing curly bracket and only after that IDE will format curly brackets as I want, it will put curly brackets on a new lines:

- [http://i.imgur.com/19FWufk.gif](https://i.imgur.com/19FWufk.gifv)

What I want is when I type opening curly bracket and then press enter, I want IDE to automatically put opening curly bracket on a new line, then add empty line, then add closing curly bracket and focus on empty line in the end.

I don't want it to do all of that when I put opening curly bracket and then type some text afterwards(when I initialize class, for example).

I don't want any other automatic completion of other characters(quotes, parentheses, etc.)

My settings atm:

- https://i.stack.imgur.com/jopkq.png
- https://i.stack.imgur.com/kW54Z.png
- https://i.stack.imgur.com/IDvR6.png
- https://i.stack.imgur.com/4znft.png

Looks like I can't achieve what I want using default VS settings.

When I check "Automatic brace completion" it starts to automatically complete quotes and parentheses, which is really annoying because I have to switch to arrows or mouse all the time to move cursor to a proper position, so I can continue to enter code.

Is there some extension for Visual Studio to achieve what I want? I tried productivity power tools so far and couldn't achieve it either:

- https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=VisualStudioProductTeam.ProductivityPowerTools

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to turn off brackets/quotes auto-completion in Visual Studio](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11055800/how-to-turn-off-brackets-quotes-auto-completion-in-visual-studio)

Comment: Also check [this] (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31526847/automatic-brace-completion-keeps-reverting-to-selected)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try ReSharper(30 days free trial) or Code maid extension which is really good at reorganizing code (http://www.codemaid.net/)

This may also help

[How to use Visual Studio automatic brace completion to surround an existing block?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37769014/how-to-use-visual-studio-automatic-brace-completion-to-surround-an-existing-bloc)

Answer (score 1):

Looks like I've found a solution. I've downloaded and installed ReSharper and now it does what I wanted it to do: it puts an opening curly bracket on a new line, then add empty line, then add closing curly bracket and focusing cursor on empty line.
And it doesn't automatically complete quotes and round brackets:

[image: example usage gif]

To achieve that I had to turn off automatic brace completion in VS options:

[image: auto brace completion screenshot]

And then I had to configure options of ReSharper:

[image: auto insert closing brace screenshot]
[image: completion behavior screenshot]
[image: braces layout screenshot]

And now finally it works as I wanted it to! Took me several hours to achieve it, though.